# Python - Seaborn Violin plot, not doing what I want it to

Tags: python, seaborn

I am looking at examples, but everything requires a dataframe.

If I have the following dataframe:

```
x = ["G","F","E","D","C","B"]
y = [3,14,45,47,34,15]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Band': x,
     'Count': y,
    })
```

I want to create a violin plot using `Count` as the value and `Band` as the steps, so I have done this:

```
ax = sns.violinplot( y="Count", data=df)
```

which produces this:

[image]

However, I want to have the `Bands` on the `y axis`, and then the `Count` to be the size of bulge for each grade. Do you have to only use `continuous values` on the `y axis`?

**Edit:**

What I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: It's not too clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Can you enhance the question with a little bit more explanation?

Comment: Sure, I'm heading back to my desk in a few minutes. I'll quickly doodle what I want to show :)

Comment: Hey, I have added a doodle of what I want it to look like. Maybe I misunderstand what violin plots can do. I know that it is meant to have something like female on one side and male on the other, but I just want it to be symmetrical showing just the count per band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Violin plots are usually used to depict the kernel density of a dataset. It's not directly clear what a kernel density of a discrete dataset should be, but you can of course assume your discrete case to be continuous by mapping the letters `"B", "C", "D", ...` to integers `0,1,2,...` and then plotting the violin.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = ["G","F","E","D","C","B"]
y = [3,14,45,47,34,15]

data = []
for i, yi in enumerate(y):
    data.extend([i]*yi)

sns.violinplot(y=data)
plt.yticks(range(len(x)), x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This gives some general hint on the distribution of letters. However for quantitative use, one would probably rather plot a bar plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = ["G","F","E","D","C","B"]
y = [3,14,45,47,34,15]

plt.barh(np.arange(len(x)), y)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(x)), x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now you may of course style that bar plot in a way similar to a violin, or maybe call it "christmastree plot".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np

x = ["G","F","E","D","C","B"]
y = [3,14,45,47,34,15]

plt.barh(np.arange(len(x)), y, height=1, color="C0")
plt.barh(np.arange(len(x)), -np.array(y), height=1, color="C0")

plt.yticks(np.arange(len(x)), x)

# create strictly positive ticklabels
posfmt = mticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x,_: "{:g}".format(np.abs(x)))
plt.gca().get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(posfmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. That was both helpful and REALLY informative; and has answered my question perfectly!